# Eavesdropping and sniffing attacks

Tags: network, penetration-test

Assume we have two routers connected by a link. Speaking of eavesdropping and sniffing attacks, does it technically appear at link itself or at the routers? If at the routers, does it imply that these routers must be compromised first ?

Comment: Are you asking where eavesdropping occurs? If so, it can occur anywhere along the communication channel. Whether or not that means a device is compromised depends on the security that the device is supposed to provide. For example, non-encrypted communication on an open WAP could be eavesdropped without anything being compromised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either this or that.

If a router is compromised, it can send a copy of the traffic to whoever's controlling it.

If neither router is compromised, but an attacker has physical access to the line connecting them, he may be able to sniff.
Copper wires are relatiely easy to sniff - a simple instrument placed near the wire can sniff the signal.
Optic fibers are harder to sniff - you must cut them and insert a repeater, that would also server as a sniffer.

Also, the link between two routers might not be a simple physical link - it could include switches, which might also be compromised.